# Get element tag name and length with Jquery each

Tags: jquery, each, tagname

I'm trying to get info about all element tags and there frequency in the page, this is how I find the tag, very simple:

```
$('body *').each(function(){
var string = this.tagName;
```

But the length doesnt catch up:

```
var count =  $(this).length;
```

It gives me `1` while there are two divs, example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrgh6/1/)

I can solve this problem by removing the `each` function but I need it for the tagname. I have to use body * for my project so I can't refer directly to the divs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it:

```
var count =  $(string, 'body').length;
```

Comment: Very simple, I like it:) Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You're not iterating each *kind* of tag with `body *`, you're iterating over each tag individually. The length will *always* be one, because `this` is always a single DOM element.

You should enumerate the tags you want to count, and iterate over them:

```
var tags = ['div', 'li', 'a'];

tags.forEach(function (tag) {
  console.log(tag, "appears", $('body ' + tag).length, 'times');
});
```

Output from running in the JS console on this page:

```
div appears 141 times
li appears 66 times
a appears 179 times
```